# Registering a Bower Package with Remote Repository in Artifactory isn't saving

Tags: bower, artifactory

Having some trouble registering a bower package to a remote repository which should be possible with the version I have (artifactory.version:   4.9.1)

So there is a repo there thats setup and it has a URL of http://mygetserver.domain.com/git which hits the gitolite page for browsing the git repos (which seems odd)

The registry url is pointing at the default of https://bower.herokuapp.com/
With the Bower Settings pointing to Custom and a default URL of {0}/{1}/archive/{2}.{3} - Again that feels weird but I have no idea whats expected in there

So when I try and register a package with

```
bower register nh-styles  git@mygetserver.domain.com:nh-styles.git --verbose
```

I get an error to say

> Error: Unknown error: 404 - Unable to determine coordinates from url git@mygetserver.domain.com:nh-styles.git

If I change that to use ssh:// first then it works

> C:\Dev>bower register nh-styles
>   ssh://git@mygetserver.domain.com/nh-styles.git --verbose bower
>   nh-styles#*              resolve
>   ssh://git@mygetserver.domain.com/nh-styles.git#* bower nh-styles#*
>   checkout v0.0.4 bower nh-styles#*              old-git It seems you
>   are using an old version of git, it will be slower and propitious to
>   errors! bower nh-styles#*         invalid-meta nh-styles is missing
>   "ignore" entry in bower.json bower nh-styles#*             resolved
>   ssh://git@mygetserver.domain.com/nh-styles.git#0.0.4 ? Registering a
>   package will make it installable via the registry
>   (http://myart.artifactorydomain.com:8081/artifactory/api/bower/bower-nh-git
>   ? Registering a package will make it installable via the registry
>   (http://myart.artifactorydomain.com:8081/artifactory/api/bower/bower-nh-git
>   ), continue? Yes bower nh-styles               register
>   ssh://git@mygetserver.domain.com/nh-styles.git
>
> Package nh-styles registered successfully! All valid semver tags on
>   ssh://git@mygetserver.domain.com/nh-styles.git will be available as
>   versions. To publish a new version, just release a valid semver tag.
>
> Run bower info nh-styles to list the available versions.
>
> C:\Dev>bower info nh-styles bower nh-styles#*           not-cached
>   art://nh-styles/nh-styles#* bower nh-styles#*              resolve
>   art://nh-styles/nh-styles#* bower                         EREQUEST
>   Request to
>   http://myart.artifactorydomain.com:8081/artifactory/api/bower/bower-nh-git/refs/nh-styles/n
>   h-styles returned 404 status code.
>
> Additional error details: [object Object]

Yet when I try and Info nothing shows. Every time I resubmit I'm getting a 201 rather than a package exists issue. So basically why is it not being saved? Artifactory logs are showing nothing I can see. Anything else I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you must include `ssh://` is that the bower resolver need to know what protocol it has to use when accessing the specified url, this is also documented [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bower+Repositories#BowerRepositories-RegisteringBowerPackages).  Also I noticed you used `domain.com:nh-styles.git` this is not a valid url, because of the `:` -- it might also work like this without the `ssh://` part i'm  not sure.

The way registering a package with Artifactory works is that it simply acts as the registry in a sense that it simply keeps a mapping of the package name to the git url you gave it.  That's also why registering a package will have no other apparent effect (except for the `201` response).
The behavior is pretty much identical to the bower public registry in this aspect.

The error itself you're getting is because Artifactory can't find the git repo you're referring to in the registered git repository - check that the repo at the url you gave is accessible - you can also turn on [debug logs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Log+Files) on `org.artifactory.addon.bower` to see the exact error Artifactory encountered if it's not already printing something to the log about this.